# Why Kalista can't bind champions after the first minutes?

Tags: league-of-legends

There was a game with a noob player trying Kalista.

The player never paid attention to the item until I realised for like 15 minutes of the game, then I told him to try binding me.

When the player tries to bind, the sound comes out but not the ritual.

As a matter of fact I remember that it happened with me before: it failed many times, no success.

Is this a known bug? Are there any other requirements?

Comment: Maybe he issued a move command while the binding ritual was channeled? Just a wild guess. I'm not sure though if the ritual can be canceled during its' channel period.

Comment: Wiki reads "during which both Kalista and her target are unable to act and her target performs their death animation."  Only thing I can think of is a range issue.  No definitive proof or trials so just commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Kalista's Black Spear, a binding can **only** be made within the **first three minutes**. With a binding you're pretty much dedicating yourself to the person you're oathsworn to, as you're expected to be paired for the rest of the game. It's not a glitch or a bug. If you miss the opportunity, that's it.The player can re-buy the spear at the shop in the first three minutes of the early game to ensure that in case there was a wrong binding at start game or if the player forgot while they were buying items they can still bind. But after the three minutes, it's just tough luck.

EDIT: As a response to the comment to my question, I'll further the answer more.
You can re-buy The Black Spear, but it's un-usable after a certain time frame. I've experienced this myself multiple times when I've had people quit. In fact I've done what the OP has done, and it's the same thing. When Kalista is bound to someone, they stay bound with her. It's how her game mechanic is supposed to work. If twenty minutes pass and the person Kalista is bound to AFKs/Quits/Disconnects, you **cannot** rebind, even if you have a new Black Spear. I'll also say that this effect does indeed happen if you forget to bind your partner. I learned a very harsh lesson very quickly when I discovered that I couldn't bind after 10 minutes into a game. You do have a time limit in which to bind your partner.

[Source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-421-notes#patch-kalista)

Comment: The patch notes you linked just say that you can rebind any time in the first three minutes, not that the first bind can only be made in the first three minutes.  They seem to be outdated anyway, since you can rebuy the item in the store now to rebind at any time, as the other answer notes.

Comment: You can re-buy it, yes, but it's un-usable after a certain time frame. I've experienced this myself multiple times when I've had people quit. In fact I've done what the OP has done, and it's the same thing. When Kalista is bound to someone, they stay bound with her. If twenty minutes pass and the person Kalista is bound to AFKs/Quits/Disconnects, you **cannot** rebind, even if you have a new Black Spear.

Comment: What you're saying sounds more like a bug than a feature, but you never know with Riot.

Comment: Chances are it's a side-effect of when the ability to re-bind within the first few minutes was introduced. At other times I'd view it "as use common sense or suffer the penalty" kind of a thing. Kalista is in no way a solo-champ, she relies on her Oathsworn throughout all stages of the game.

Answer (score 1):

You can rebuy the item from the store for 0 gold and bind to someone different whenever you want, they must have been canceling it somehow or maybe the person he was binding didn't accept it.

Comment: You cant not accept it

Comment: Really? I thought you had to click on it to accept it. Either way it can be purchased or sold in the store for 0g so there is no limitation on when in the game it can be used.